# External hdd not working when connected to Hub USB 3.0 which is connected to other USB hub (daisy chain)

Tags: daisychaining

I found strange problem with 2 usb hubs connected to each other:

---

Legend:

```
HUB_A_passive_3.0_4x - USB HUB 3.0 passive (4 ports)
HUB_B_active_3.0_7x  - USB HUB 3.0 active (7 ports)
HUB_C_active_2.0_4x  - USB HUB 2.0 active (4 ports)
external_hdd_passive - WD My Passport Ultra (passive)
Pendrive : Patriot 128GB Rage Elite 400/100MB/s (USB 3.1 Gen. 1)
```

---

All power source were connected and checked that were working.

OLD SETUP (working):

```
notebook <---> HUB_A_passive_3.0_4x <----->  HUB_C_active_2.0_4x <-----> external_hdd_passive
NEW SETUP (not working):

notebook <---> HUB_A_passive_3.0_4x <----->  HUB_B_active_3.0_7x  <-----> external_hdd_passive it doesn't work

notebook <---> HUB_A_passive_3.0_4x <----->  HUB_B_active_3.0_7x  <-----> Pendrive it doesn't work
```

if I attach HUB_B_3.0_7x directly to the notebook it works:

```
notebook <---> HUB_B_active_3.0_7x  <-----> external_hdd_passive
```

Do you have any idea why with older active USB hub this setup works, but with newer USB 3.0 hub it does not ?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the hub may be the problem is one of the used cable. Also some active USB hubs violate the spec by sending power not only to devices but also upstream which may confuse or even destroy the upstream device. If cascading multiple hubs I would try to avoid hubs of different manufacturer or at least hubs with different USB hub chips.

Comment: I use the same manufacturer (3 hubs: active usb 2.0, passive usb 3.0, active usb 3.0). I checked when I connect in this way:


 `nootbook <---> HUB_C_active_2.0_4x (but in passive mode - without power supply) <-----> HUB_B_active_3.0_7x  <-----> external_hdd_passive`

it works. So it seems that sth wrong is with `HUB_A_passive_3.0_4x` ?